# How can I install FFmpeg so that pkg-config can find it?

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, libavcodec, pkg-config

I want to use the ffmpeg libraries in my program. These are libavformat and libavcodec. To link them, I'm trying to use pkg-config.

I cannot get pkg-config to find these libraries.

When I run
 `pkg-config --modversion libavcodec`
I get
`Can't find libavcodec.pc in any of C:/Strawberry/c/lib/pkgconfig`

Which should mean that I don't have ffmpeg installed.

However, I did install ffmpeg.
I'm using Windows so I installed ffmpeg with the Chocolatey package manager. This seems to have only given me the ffmpeg program and not its libraries.

On MacOS simply using homebrew to install ffmpeg installs all the right files.

Is there a difference on Windows? How can I get the dev package?

SOME MORE INFO:

I'm compiling this using CMake-js as a node addon. This is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(FFMpeg)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(AVCODEC    REQUIRED    IMPORTED_TARGET libavcodec)
pkg_check_modules(AVFILTER   REQUIRED    IMPORTED_TARGET libavformat)
pkg_check_modules(AVDEVICE   REQUIRED    IMPORTED_TARGET libavdevice)
pkg_check_modules(AVUTIL     REQUIRED    IMPORTED_TARGET libavutil)
pkg_check_modules(SWRESAMPLE REQUIRED    IMPORTED_TARGET libswresample)
pkg_check_modules(SWSCALE    REQUIRED    IMPORTED_TARGET libswscale)

add_library(FFMpeg INTERFACE IMPORTED GLOBAL)

target_include_directories(
    FFmpeg INTERFACE
    ${AVCODEC_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${AVFILTER_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${AVDEVICE_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${AVUTIL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${SWRESAMPLE_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${SWSCALE_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

target_link_options(
    FFmpeg INTERFACE
    ${AVCODEC_LDFLAGS}
    ${AVFILTER_LDFLAGS}
    ${AVDEVICE_LDFLAGS}
    ${AVUTIL_LDFLAGS}
    ${SWRESAMPLE_LDFLAGS}
    ${SWSCALE_LDFLAGS}
```

I also found this in the output, which might explain why pkg-config is looking in `C:\Strawberry?`

```
-- Found PkgConfig: C:/Strawberry/perl/bin/pkg-config.bat (found version "0.26")
-- Checking for module 'libavcodec'
--   Can't find libavcodec.pc in any of C:/Strawberry/c/lib/pkgconfig
```

Comment: What environment are you running pkg-config in? Is C:\Strawberry something to do with Strawberry Perl?

Comment: I've edited the question to include more details

Comment: Do you want FFmpeg compiled for MSVC or for MinGW? [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075) has a MinGW version (and pkg-config does work there), but I'm not sure how well that will work with Strawberry Perl.

Comment: Ultimately I want to create a windows app that utilises the libraries inside ffmpeg (libavcodec libavformat libavdevice ....) to do some video manipulation, in a node program. I'm using a C++ addon for this, Any way I can use any of these libraries in my code will do. I just can't seem to get this one step complete. The pkg-config approach was suggested by a tutorial but they were on MacOS and simply installed ffmpeg from brew and were ready to go.

Comment: There is a "ffmpeg-shared" package in Chocolatey, but it does not include any .pc files.

Comment: Any suggestions on ways to install a version that does have .pc files?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with the same problem:

I looked at the folder structure of the linux and macos packages, and they include all the libraries. The Windows version that is included in the main download or any package manager does not contain these libraries.

If you're on Windows you will want a build from [here](https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases) (BtbN FFmpeg Builds) and get the full version.

Now all I have to do is get it to work with pkg-config.